# UWP AutoSuggestionBox Search Utility using my Model

Tags: search, uwp

I'm Currently Working on a Project Designing a Media Player with a Library Ill post the Code for that Method, What i'm trying to Achieve is using the **AutoSuggestionBox** To Search through my library **GridView** items then Querying one of the Songs and highlighting it in the **GridView**

Here's my Code for the Library

```
private ObservableCollection<MusicLib> MusicList = new ObservableCollection<MusicLib>();
private StackPanel CurrentTarget;
private string content;

public Browsing()
{

    this.InitializeComponent();


}

private async void btn_Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{


    //Create a new picker
    var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

    //Add filetype filters. 

    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");


    //Set picker start location to the video library
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;







    var files = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();



    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        StorageItemThumbnail currentThumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 200, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
        var albumCover = new BitmapImage();
        albumCover.SetSource(currentThumb);

        var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
        var musicname = musicProperties.Title;
        var musicdur = musicProperties.Duration;

        var artist = musicProperties.Artist;
        if (artist == "")
        {
            artist = "Unkown";
        }

        var album = musicProperties.Album;
        if (album == "")
        {
            album = "Unkown";
        }
        MusicList.Add(new MusicLib
        {
            FileName = musicname,
            Artist = artist,
            Album = album,
            Duration = musicdur,
            AlbumCover = albumCover,
            MusicPath = file.Path
        });

    }
}
```

Here's my Context Menu for Deleting Tracks(It's a Work in Progress i'm Probaly missing something stupid)

```
private void ListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridView listView = (GridView)sender;
    allContactsMenuFlyout.ShowAt(listView, e.GetPosition(listView));
    var a = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as MusicList;
    content = a.text;
}

private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in MusicList.ToList())
    {
        if (item.text == content)
        {
            MusicList.Remove(item);
        }
    }
    content = "";
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid Background="White" Name="MyGrid">

            <AutoSuggestBox Name="Search" />
    <GridView RightTapped="ListView_RightTapped"  Name="mylist" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MusicList}" Margin="0,37,0,0">

        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel  Name="Stacky" PointerEntered="myList_PointerEntered" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100" Source="{Binding AlbumCover}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel  >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Album}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.Resources>
            <MenuFlyout x:Name="allContactsMenuFlyout">
                <MenuFlyout.Items>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Edit"  Text="Edit" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="Remove" Text="Remove"    Click="Remove_Click" />
                </MenuFlyout.Items>
            </MenuFlyout>
        </GridView.Resources>
    </GridView>
```

**Model**

```
namespace Mp3Player
{
    class MusicLib
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }
        public string Album { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
        public string MusicPath { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage AlbumCover { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To be more specific on my Question im trying to Query one the object's from my **Model** to "find" that specific track so like **FileName** For example

I know with the Auto Suggestion box there are 3 Methods you need to use one of which is a **Query** Method I'm just at a loss as to what to do so if someone could provide a Example possibly, I Will appreciate it, And Post my Project on GitHub for future Ref for anyone who's new to this like i am .

Answer (score 0):

**AutoSuggestBox** has been documented with detail of its design and how to use it along with its code examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box).

> This is a typical AutoSuggestBox

```
<AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="200"
            TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
            QuerySubmitted="AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
            SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen"/>
```

**Backend**

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Only get results when it was a user typing,
    // otherwise assume the value got filled in by TextMemberPath
    // or the handler for SuggestionChosen.
    if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
    {
        //Set the ItemsSource to be your filtered dataset
        //sender.ItemsSource = dataset;// Here you will filter your music list and only send back the data which matches with the text in your autosuggest box.

    }
}


private void AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    // Set sender.Text. You can use args.SelectedItem to build your text string.
}


private void AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
    {
        // User selected an item from the suggestion list, take an action on it here.
    }
    else
    {
        // Use args.QueryText to determine what to do.
    }
}
```

In your case you have the **collection of MusicLib** objects and you need to filter with **FileName** so the **DataSet** you send back as filtered data will be from your collection. for that you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq) or just a simple foreach loop if you prefer that.

Note that when you keep filtering your collection but if you change the collection for filtering then you need to keep a second collection as well which will always have all the music tracks,and once you are comfortable with basic concepts, dont hesitate to explore : [AdvancedCollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/helpers/advancedcollectionview) by **WindowsCommunityToolkit** which makes filtering much simpler and powerful for you.

**GoodLuck**

Comment: Thanks alot for the Very understanding Answer, I will be trying this. And will report on my Progress. Im very new to the Development world. But im always interested in learning! The Goal is if i get the time to eventually have the library save to a model or Xaml Doc using something like LightDB so i will definitely take a look at the AdvancedCollectionView

Comment: for database you also have the option of sqlite